# How to print Time out without waiting python script running from php in window8

Tags: php, python, windows

I have a PHP script that runs a python script with **exec("C:/Users/Lenovo/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/testing/timeout.py")**;. It works nicely, but I don't want to wait that python script to finish. Also I need to run remaining php code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried: `exec("start C:/Users/Lenovo/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/testing/timeout.py")`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, since you're using windows would be to run the command in background using `start` like that:

```
exec("start C:/Users/Lenovo/Python26/python C:/xampp/htdocs/testing/timeout.py");
```

Comment: I would like to display "Time out"[ echo "Time out";] on browser without waiting python script running.Thanks a lot.